# How to use nested loops propely

Tags: python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

I have this nested loop in my project (it's a lot more complicated of course I just simplify it so you can see what I mean). I know there is no label and goto in python, I just want to show what I want to do.

From line `#goto third` I want go back to place where you can see `#label third`.

I tried different setups of my loops but they never do what I want

```
import time

onoff = "on"

t=0

while onoff == "on":
    #label first
    for x in range (5):
        print("first loop")
        time.sleep(1)
        for y in range (5):
            print("second loop")
            time.sleep(1)
            p = 0    #for testing
            t=0   #for testing
            if p != 5:
                if t == 0:
                    print("third loop")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    p2 = 5    #for testing
                    t=0
                    if p2 != 5:   #label third
                        if t == 0:
                            print("go back to first loop")
                            time.sleep(1)
                            #goto first
                        else:
                            print("lock")
                            #lock.acquire()
                    else:
                        if t == 0:
                            print("go back to third loop")
                            p2 = 3
                            time.sleep(1)
                            #goto third
                        else:
                            print("lock")
                            #lock.acquire()
                else:
                    print("lock")
                    #lock.acquire()
```

Every path in this nested loops seems to work fine but I want my loop to go back to `#label third` from `#goto third` and it goes back to #label first. How can I change my loops to make it possible?

Comment: It'll eventually have to go from `goto third` to `label first` when the `for y in range(5)` loop completes for every x. If you want more loop control, then I suggest using a `while` instead of a `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions like `goto first` which break 'for' loops are evil in many ways. `While` loops are more elegant, but maybe a 'state machine' like solution is better for you. Something like:

```
state = 0
while is_on:
   if state == 0:             # do outer loop things
       <do things>
       state = 1              # to do inner loop things

   elif state == 1:
       n = 0
          # do inner loop things 
       n += 1
       if n == 5:
           state = 0

   elif state == 2:            # do even more nested things
       p = 0
       if <some condition>:
           state = 0
       p += 1
       if p == 5:
          state = <whatever>
```

A state machine permits much more flexibility. Also, it won't cause as much indentation as nested loop. If the complexity gets larger, there are some libraries which can help you. Interesting links on Finite State Machines ([FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)):

https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StateMachine.html

https://www.python-course.eu/finite_state_machine.php

Comment: Yeah, I think I can make it using this method. Thank you.